# How come all my comments were deleted, leaving the other ones?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

[How to get the number of fields in a variable of type struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75857975/how-to-get-the-number-of-fields-in-a-variable-of-type-struct)

There was a longer exchange of comments, I discovered today that all of mine were deleted and all the others were left untouched.

How can someone imagine that there can be a sane discussion when arguments of one side are deleted (including pointers to code); leaving nonsense afterward (people who send me messages and apparently no answers form me, and then references to non-existing comments).

Is there a policy about that somewhere?

Comment: Comments aren't designed to be permanent; presumably someone flagged yours as no longer needed. Considering you were the OP, perhaps they were comments that should have been [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75857975/edit)s to the post? If so, then they were rightfully removed.

Comment: There is comment of yours in that question. If any comment was deleted, it's impossible to venture an opinion as to why without knowing any thing about this comments.

Comment: Your claim isn't entirely correct, since I did leave one of your comments. I deleted the other ones, along with several other comments from myself and other users because the conversation wasn't going anywhere. 1) comments are transient by nature; 2) comments aren't meant for **extended** discussion; 3) the place where to dispute question closure is meta, not comments for the reasons 1 and 2. I deemed entirely unnecessary to leave there all the (inconclusive) back and forth

Comment: I shall also note that some of those comments were quite closer to being rants about the close process rather than discussion about the merits of your question

Comment: @blackgreen how do you imagine leaving comments that refer to comments that were deleted? Do you find that normal to simply censor another point of view (and code examples)? To me, this is simply misusing mod power to silence others when it is convenient - the back and forth was plain documented discussion. Anyway, this is fortunately SO and not normal life so feel free to delete that one too so that there can be more downvotes. Seriously - over the 10 or whatever years I am in SO the Go community is one where only geniuses can live in their circle and bad luck if you want to learn something.

Comment: Are the duplicate targets in that question suitable or not?

Comment: @WoJ clarifications / code examples etc. should ideally go in your question itself. If you want to demonstrate your question is not a duplicate it should be edited.

Answer (score 17):

Here’s screenshots of the comment thread, so that everyone can see what we're talking about. (images not inlined because are rendered quite big)

- [part 1 of 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4bEG.jpg)
- [part 2 of 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY12X.jpg)
- [part 3 of 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHg0X.jpg)

Some of your comments were borderline rude, there's no way around it. Examples:

> this community is a complete mess [...] I really hope the insufferable know-it-all who live here [...]

> In a normal, sane community this gets transformed into an answer and we are done. Here we have nonsense overexcited duplicates and comments about questions that do not make sense

The rest of the comment thread is people trying to show you why the chosen canonical apply, slowly digressing into Typescript and whatnot.

You also [edited your question with unhelpful commentary](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75857975/revisions) that doesn't belong into the question. I'll repeat what I already said in the comments to this question:

1. comments are transient by nature;
2. comments aren't meant for **extended** discussion
3. the place where to dispute question closure (after having edited the question) is meta, not comments for the reasons 1 and 2

I reject your claims to have been ([in your words](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423883/how-come-all-my-comments-were-deleted-leaving-the-other-ones#comment951953_423883)) "misusing mod power to silence others when it is convenient". Your comments started off as ranty and quickly digressed into progressively unrelated conversation about duplicate closure and Typescript.

There was nothing "convenient" to me there. It wasn't even me who closed your question to begin with. And there was nothing to "silence", since you can always come to Meta to dispute duplicate closure — or even challenge comment deletion, if you wish. Though passive-aggressive remarks like those you have been posting aren't the way to go.

Comment: OK, I give up. As for TS - you said that you do not know a language where my question works, I gave you a ready example of code, to which you replied that with strict checks it would not (but it does). Then that the duplicates were correct, to which I gave, again, code to show that are not -- and at the end all of this was deleted. This is not how a sane organization is managed.

Comment: Keeping the deleted comments aside I'd agree that the question was not a duplicate of the first target, the second target does apply though. It was quite obvious OP had a misunderstanding about how the structs / variables worked, either that should have been addressed in an answer or an appropriate duplicate target found.

Comment: "borderline"? Rude.

Comment: I'll meet it halfway though, this *site* is a mess. Because for one, there is no community. Only a huge pile of people doing their own thing in isolation.